# Does "sp_OACreate" Create unique output Object?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am making a soap call to API server using my store procedure. This SP is being called during the process, i am noticing a behavior when more than 1 person calls the SP at same time, it seems to end the first call leaving process half completed.

store procedure has following code, is that because i am destroying the object at the end and 2nd process finishes before 1st ends, leaving 1st process half completed?

i am using following SQL Server:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64) 
Oct 28 2016 18:17:30 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)



DECLARE @object int              
   ,@response varchar(8000)              
   ,@responseText varchar(8000),@Post nvarchar(30)    
   ,@status varchar(50),@ResponseStatus INT 

     Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @Object OUT;            
     Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, @Post,@Url,'false'
     Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authorization', @Authorization           
     EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'application/vnd.api+json'              
     EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send', null, @SoapAction              
     EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'Status', @Status OUT            
           
     INSERT INTO #Data (xml)              
     EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'responseText'               
     EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Comment: I really recommend using CLR objects over those old compatibility procedures.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-oacreate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) the OLE object is destroyed at the end of the transaction batch, so you shouldn't need the explicit `EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object`

Comment: Have you set up a test with overlapping `EXEC`s? What happens if you temporarily comment out that `sp_OADestroy` and run your test?

Comment: I haven't done a loading testing, assuming it will work which it did but now that site is little busy and i started to get this random msgs that process isn't completing.
Reason i am destorying the object, is to be in safe side that i don't create too many objects which may cause another problem.

Comment: Why would you do this at all, just use Powershell or similar to push data into SQL Server. T-SQL is not a generalized scripting language

Comment: Larnu and Charlieface are right, but unfortunately we sometimes get saddled with bad assumptions in legacy development that tie our hands to using a particular tool, regardless of how awful it is in practice. You should be planning for how to move these API calls out of your database and into an application layer, but that by itself doesn't make the question invalid.

Comment: #DavidBrowne, this is no way near to the question what you seems to believe, don't just close it saying it's duplicate, i am facing a problem and asked a question, let other people answer, you have authority doesn't mean you can say two different questions are same.